# ng-change doesn't work on input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and currently struggling with the following problem.

As you can see [here in my plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SaBsJVZfHsY4dnaNIfXK?p=preview) I can change the value of the `$scope.myDate.value`.

The problem now is, that I can't work with this scope in a function, when adding `ng-change="barFunc()"` to the `<input>`.

How is it possible to work with `ng-change` or `ng-watch` here?
It would be great if someone could make my plnkr work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//rawgithub.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/1.0.3/dist/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      input {margin: 45px 0 15px 0;}
      pre{padding: 15px; text-align: left;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div ng-controller="foo">
                <input type="datetime" class="form-control" date-time ng-model="myDate.value"
                  ng-change="barFunc()" format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" placeholder="Select datetime">
                <pre>myDate: {{myDate.value}}</pre>
                <pre>myDate + " abc": {{ custom.value }}</pre>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker/1.0.3/dist/index.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('demo', ['datePicker']).controller('foo',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.myDate = {
        value: ''
      };
      
    $scope.barFunc = function() {
      $scope.custom.value = $scope.myDate.value + " abc";
    };
}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `$scope.custom` before you can access to `$scope.custom.value`

Answer (score 2):

I would use $watch in this case:

in your controller:

```
$scope.custom = {
    value : ''
};

$scope.$watch('myDate.value', function() {
    $scope.barFunc();
});

$scope.barFunc = function() {
  $scope.custom.value = $scope.myDate.value + " abc";
};
```

or in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2jwNrFDpVWITMmMTgcli?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for this ng-watch example ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a watcher like this:

```
$scope.$watch('myDate', function(oldValue, newValue) {
$scope.barFunc(newValue);
```

});

but you'll also need to define your custom object:

```
  $scope.custom = {
    value: ''
  };
```

and it should work.  I don't feel like this is the best solution - I generally feel like if I'm setting watchers because I don't understand why something's not working as expected then it's better to figure out why it's not working.  I get that's what you're trying to do, and am only offering this as something that would solve your problem quickly if that's what you need.

Comment: in case it's not clear in my answer above - I don't know why the ng-change doesn't work here, even after you define your custom object, and didn't have the time to figure that one out.  Will be pretty interested to see if anyone else offers a solution to that part of the issue.